Showing that Euclidean balls are Jordan measurable
I'm trying to show that open and closed Euclidean balls
$B(x,r) := \{y \in \mathbf{R}^d: |y-x|< r \}$
and
$\bar{B}(x,r) = \{y \in \mathbf{R}^d: |y-x|< r\}$ in $\mathbf{R}^d$ are Jordan measurable with their measures being $c_d r^d$ with $c_d>0$ being a constant that depends only on $d$.
Here is my attempt:
We say that  $B(x,r)$ is Jordan measurable if $\forall \epsilon > 0 $, $\exists \underline{B}, \overline{B} \subset \mathbf{R}^d$ where $ \underline{B} \subset B(x,r) \subset \overline{B} $
such that $\overline{B}  - \underline{B} < \epsilon $
Let $B(x,r) := \{y \in \mathbf{R}^d : |y - x| < r \}$
We define  $ \underline{B}, \overline{B} $ as
$\forall y \in B(x,r)$
$$\underline{B} := \{y \in \mathbf{R}^d : |(y+\frac{\epsilon}{2})-x| < r \}$$
$$\overline{B} := \{ y \in \mathbf{R}^d : |(y-\frac{\epsilon}{2})-x| < r \}$$
we calculate the difference between $\overline{B}$ and $\underline{B}$:
$$ \overline{B} -  \underline{B} = |(y+ \frac{\epsilon}{2}) - x | - |(y-\frac{\epsilon}{2})-x| = |(y +\frac{\epsilon}{2}) - x| - |y - \frac{\epsilon}{2} - x | \leq |y + \frac{\epsilon}{2} - x - y + \frac{\epsilon}{2} + x | = |\epsilon|  $$
therefore $$ \overline{B} -  \underline{B} \leq |\epsilon|  $$
Idem for $\bar{B}(x,r)$
Now we want to find the measure of open and closed balls.
$r$ is the radius of euclidean balls. Therefore $2r$ is the diameter.
for the sake of simplicity, we place the ball on an interval of $[0 , 2r] \times [0 , 2r]$
Now we will separate the Euclidean ball into small boxes.
We divide both horizontal and vertical intervals into n pieces and $j \in \mathbf{N}$ is the indice of each nth box. Each small box is $[ x_i , x_i +\frac{2r}{n_j}]^d$
measure of each box is $ |x_i +\frac{2r}{n} - x_i|^d = (\frac{2r}{n})^d = 4 \frac{r^2}{n^d} = \frac{4}{n_j^d} r^d $
therefore measure of the Euclidean ball is $\sum_j^n \frac{4}{n_j} r^d $
The measure of the euclidean ball is of the form $c_d r^d$ where $c_d = \sum_j^n \frac{4}{n_j}$
I'm not sure if my idea/execution is correct because I haven't really used the euclidean norm to show that the euclidean balls are Jordan measurable.
I also think that my proof at showing the measure of the balls are of the form $c_d r^d$ is wrong but I don't see how I could improve it

Please stop pretending that everything can be treated as if it were a number. $y\in \Bbb R^d$ is not a number. It is a $d$-tuple of numbers. Just what do you mean by $y \pm \frac\epsilon 2$? And $\overline B, \underline B$ are sets. What the heck do you mean by $\overline B - \underline B$ and how can it be compared to $\epsilon$, a number?

By $y \pm \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, I tried to generate two covers of the ball, one that was $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ bigger, which my main Euclidean ball would be a subset of, I called it $\overline{B}$ and the other that would be a subset of my Euclidean ball, which I labeled $\underline{B}$ (I'm not sure if it means what I think it would but that's why I tried to say $\forall y$, so that the measures of both covers would actually change). So by comparing the measures of the covers, I tried to conclude that the difference of measure between these two covers would be smaller or equal to $\epsilon$

No. By $y \pm \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, you ignored the fact that $y$ is a vector/point in $d$-dimensional space, and $\frac \epsilon 2$ is a real number. And there is no "addition" or "subtraction" defined between points and numbers. And I did not ask you what $\overline B$ or $\underline B$ were. I asked you what this "difference" between the two sets is, and what does it mean to say that this "difference" is "less than" some number? These symbols have common meanings, but you are just throwing them together without any regard for those meaning and expecting everyone to understand your nonsense.

I think I'm starting to see what you mean.
Would writing $\epsilon = (\epsilon^1,...,\epsilon^d) \in \mathbf{R}^d$ such that for all $i = {1,...,d}$, $\epsilon^i > 0$
and $m(\overline{B}) - m(\underline{B}) > \epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$ be a better approach?

For the first, yes, you can just make $\epsilon$ a coordinate vector, and declare that inequalities involving vectors hold for each coordinate. This is a common definition in optimization, though it is not widely used in measure theory, so it should be explained. But for your latter idea, I assume $m$ is Jordan measure? But you did not place any measurability requirements on $\overline B$ and $\underline B$. And if you do, then you have to show that the particular $\overline B$ and $\underline B$ you chose are measurable, which seems harder than showing that balls are measurable.

Yes, $m$ is Jordan measure. I also thought about dividing the ball into semicircles, drawing two triangles, inside and outside of the ball (first one through the left vertex to the upper point and the second one being whose hypotenuse would be the tangent to a point of the circle) as I showed previously that solid triangles are Jordan measurable, but if I understand correctly, euclidean balls don't have to be circular so I gave up, maybe this could be a better starting point?

Not sure exactly what you mean by a "solid triangle" here, a simplex, maybe? ($d$-dimensional extension of the concept of triangle and tetrahedron.) Nor what possible definition could be given to "circular" in $d$-dimensions if not the definition of a Euclidean ball. But you are not going to be able to closely approximate a ball with just two "triangles". I suggest using the union of a collection of non-overlapping cubes of various sizes. With those you can easily obtain Jordan-measureables inner and outer sets that approximate the ball as closely as you need.

Thank you very much!
